# PYODBC: Passing multiple WHERE conditions as variables

Tags: variables, select, pyodbc

pyodbc (technically pypyodbc) on SQL SERVER (windows) where I have a SELECT statement that has a join and two WHERE conditions. Each parameterized WHERE condition works when in a query by itself:

```
 bhfc_cursor.execute("""\
    select inc_auth.staff_id, inc_auth.rank, inc_auth.assignment, inc_auth.dttm from INC_AUTH
     INNER JOIN INC_MAIN ON inc_auth.inci_id = inc_main.inci_id
      where inc_main.inci_id = (?) """ ,this_incid)
    mutual_aid_fdid = bhfc_cursor.fetchone()

    bhfc_cursor.execute("""\
    select inc_auth.staff_id, inc_auth.rank, inc_auth.assignment, inc_auth.dttm from INC_AUTH
     INNER JOIN INC_MAIN ON inc_auth.inci_id = inc_main.inci_id
      where inc_auth.auth_type = (?) """,auth_type)
    mutual_aid_fdid = bhfc_cursor.fetchone()
```

But if I try to make it into a compound where with AND, it bombs:

```
   bhfc_cursor.execute("""\
    select inc_auth.staff_id, inc_auth.rank, inc_auth.assignment, inc_auth.dttm from INC_AUTH
     INNER JOIN INC_MAIN ON inc_auth.inci_id = inc_main.inci_id
      where inc_auth.auth_type = (?) and inc_main.inci_id = (?) """,auth_type, this_incid)
    mutual_aid_fdid = bhfc_cursor.fetchone()
```

error:

```
  File "C:\Users\bucky\OneDrive\Python_Installs\PycharmProjects\ReadSQLWireNFIRS\ReadSQQLWriteNFIRS.py", line 228, in <module>
    bhfc_cursor.execute("""\
  File "C:\Users\bucky\OneDrive\Python_Installs\PycharmProjects\ReadSQLWireNFIRS\Lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1617, in execute
    check_success(self, ret)
  File "C:\Users\bucky\OneDrive\Python_Installs\PycharmProjects\ReadSQLWireNFIRS\Lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1007, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "C:\Users\bucky\OneDrive\Python_Installs\PycharmProjects\ReadSQLWireNFIRS\Lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 987, in ctrl_err
    raise DatabaseError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error')
```

I know one of the princple points in asking a question is "what have you tried"?  Well, I've tried a couple dozen things.  Making it into a different passing format with %s instead of (?).  Making the two variables into a list.  Or tuple.  I've been plugging at this for three hours now and I've tried everything I can think of and everything I've found while searching.  As you can probably infer, this is sort of greek to me- I see many answers where people much smarter than me know the mechanics of where things get interpreted- in the driver or the DB or wherever- so I'm not really sure what the difference is in the "?", "(?)", the %s, %d, %b, %f formats, but I can find anything that works.

The type of inci_id is <class 'pypyodbc.TupleRow..Row'> while auth_type is <class 'list'>.  Thanks.

p.s. this is an internal ETL type program that will never be exposed to the outside world, so SQL injection concerns are minimal, although I know I should get into the habit of writing code that prevents them regardless...

EDIT: while looking at this again, I realized the 2nd table isn't even necessary.  The table that has the columns I want also has the other INCI_ID column.  But even that one fails with the same "count field incorrect.." error.

````
    bhfc_cursor.execute("""\
    select inc_auth.staff_id, inc_auth.rank, inc_auth.assignment, inc_auth.dttm from INC_AUTH
      where inc_auth.auth_type = (?) and inc_auth.inci_id = (?) """,auth_type, this_incid)
    mutual_aid_fdid = bhfc_cursor.fetchone()```

ANOTHER EDIT:  I replaced one of the variables with a constant and the query works. Although it was somewhat obvious, this proves that the problem is with the variable substitution and not the query itself:
````

```
bhfc_cursor.execute("""\
select inc_auth.staff_id, inc_auth.rank, inc_auth.assignment, inc_auth.dttm from INC_AUTH
  where (inc_auth.auth_type = 'OC' ) AND (inc_auth.inci_id = (?) ) """ , this_incid)
oic_details = bhfc_cursor.fetchone()
```

And here's some seemingly relevant stuff from an ODBC trace.  I really don't know what much of this means however.

```
ReadSQQLWriteNF fb68-77d0   ENTER SQLPrepareW 
        HSTMT               0x000001CEFFC70470
        WCHAR *             0x000001CEFF370570 [     164] "    select inc_auth.staff_id, inc_auth.rank, inc_auth.assignment, inc_auth.dttm from INC_AUTH\ a      where (inc_auth.auth_type = (?) ) AND (inc_auth.inci_id = (?) ) "
        SDWORD                   164

ReadSQQLWriteNF fb68-77d0   EXIT  SQLPrepareW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x000001CEFFC70470
        WCHAR *             0x000001CEFF370570 [     164] "    select inc_auth.staff_id, inc_auth.rank, inc_auth.assignment, inc_auth.dttm from INC_AUTH\ a      where (inc_auth.auth_type = (?) ) AND (inc_auth.inci_id = (?) ) "
        SDWORD                   164

ReadSQQLWriteNF fb68-77d0   ENTER SQLNumParams 
        HSTMT               0x000001CEFFC70470
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3C98

ReadSQQLWriteNF fb68-77d0   EXIT  SQLNumParams  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x000001CEFFC70470
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3C98 (2)

ReadSQQLWriteNF fb68-77d0   ENTER SQLDescribeParam 
        HSTMT               0x000001CEFFC70470
        UWORD                        1 
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3398
        SQLULEN *           0x000001CEFF3B3918
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3518
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3718

ReadSQQLWriteNF fb68-77d0   EXIT  SQLDescribeParam  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HSTMT               0x000001CEFFC70470
        UWORD                        1 
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3398 (-9)
        SQLULEN *           0x000001CEFF3B3918 (255)
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3518 (0)
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3718 (1)

ReadSQQLWriteNF fb68-77d0   ENTER SQLDescribeParam 
        HSTMT               0x000001CEFFC70470
        UWORD                        2 
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3798
        SQLULEN *           0x000001CEFF3B3398
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3918
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3518

ReadSQQLWriteNF fb68-77d0   EXIT  SQLDescribeParam  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HSTMT               0x000001CEFFC70470
        UWORD                        2 
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3798
        SQLULEN *           0x000001CEFF3B3398
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3918
        SWORD *             0x000001CEFF3B3518

        DIAG [07009] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index (0) 

ReadSQQLWriteNF fb68-77d0   ENTER SQLGetDiagRecW 
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 <SQL_HANDLE_STMT>
        SQLHANDLE           0x000001CEFFC70470
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x000001CEFF31A070
        SQLINTEGER *        0x000001CEFF3B2818
        SQLWCHAR *          0x000001CEFF2704E0 
        SQLSMALLINT               1024 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x000001CEFF3B2618

ReadSQQLWriteNF fb68-77d0   EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        SQLSMALLINT                  3 <SQL_HANDLE_STMT>
        SQLHANDLE           0x000001CEFFC70470
        SQLSMALLINT                  1 
        SQLWCHAR *          0x000001CEFF31A070 [       5] "07009"
        SQLINTEGER *        0x000001CEFF3B2818 (0)
        SQLWCHAR *          0x000001CEFF2704E0 [      59] "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index"
        SQLSMALLINT               1024 
        SQLSMALLINT *       0x000001CEFF3B2618 (59)
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/1c550e8878ac52a8bb04356246982fa4) works fine with pyodbc. If I try to use pypyodbc I get "TypeError: Params must be in a list, tuple, or Row"

Comment: Oh wait, you said "The type of inci_id is <class 'pypyodbc.TupleRow..Row'>". You probably need to extract a (scalar) value from the `Row` object, like `inci_id[0]`.

Comment: Thank you so much Gord for trying this out,  #2- I mistyped in my description of "inci_id".  That should've been the description of the "this_incid".  So I did attempt turning "this_incid" into a scalare with [0] with the same results.  #1- So much for "pypyodbc" and "pyodbc" being functionally equivalent"!  One of the few things I trusted and didn't check.  A quick effort to change to pyodbc resulted in a syntax error elsewhere in the code- I'll create a pyodbc branch and see it I can make it down to the statement at hand...thanks again!

Comment: Hi Gord, if you're still reading...I've narrowed it down to a different behavior of the parameterized query whether passing one or more than one.  I did switch to pyodbc and was able to construct a valid select statement, but no data is returned.  It's really weird- I think it merits a new question given this ne info so I'll ask again.  I was able to recreate your success when assigning the variable inline, but not when referencing it from a dict which was the result of a prior query.  Thanks again!